# Would it be possible to jump between prev/next Terminal command prompts?

Tags: command-line, navigation, terminal, prompt

I'm using zsh in OS X Terminal.app and for quite a while, I've been longing for a way to jump back and forth between prev/next prompts in the terminal's output.

One convenience with this would be to be able to review (and track errors at) the end of each command's output; eg. when you building stuff from source with `./configure; make; make install.` Note: I'm obviously not referring to jumping back and forth in the command-history, but for a way to take a peek at the endings of each command's output.

Has anyone heard of such functionality in the *nix (preferrably also Mac) world? Would it require some sort of OS-centric Terminal plugin, or can it be programmatically done via a shell script which can be tied to a keyboard shortcut? Maybe I'm the only one thinking about this? :)

**Edit:** Here's an example scenario: Let's say I want to compile and install some program (using standard `./configure && make && make install` procedure) and after the make command, I run into some errors. Now, the way I understand it (I may be completely wrong), the crucial error causing the make command to fail usually shows up in the last line(s) in the output, no? Anyway, at this point, I might do something like `cat INSTALL` to read up on the INSTALL document to check whether there's something I've missed. NOW, if I want to go back to see what the error was, that caused my initial make command to fail, I then have to manually scroll up to that position again, since my `cat INSTALL` command printed a ton of text after it.

I don't know if this scenario is the most elucidative – but there are many other situations where I wish I could just "jump" back to previous prompt lines and check up on previous command output; whether it was a simple `ls` command, `make`, `git status`, or whatever it was – swapping positions in the window by means of using prompt lines as "bookmark" positions seems an interesting idea to me.

Comment: I've been looking for the same thing. At least something like showing little marks for each prompt on the terminal's scrollbar, like https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/scrollbar-search-highlighter/

Comment: this is absolutely not a solution to this problem I too am faced with, but you can try to get used to printing INSTALL (and other files) to terminal with your pager, e.g. $ less INSTALL

Answer (score 0):

command + left or right goes between tabs in iterm.  is this what you are asking?

Comment: No, I want to go between different positions in the current window, where the prompt line has been. (I'm editing my question with a complimentary example.)

Answer (score 0):

Emacs has a `shell-mode` that runs a shell inside the Emacs editor, providing a rich environment of additional commands for navigating and working with shell commands. This includes commands for going to the previous/next prompt, and deleting the output from commands so you can "clean up" and issue another command.

If you aren't familiar with Emacs: to start a shell inside Emacs, run `emacs` from the shell, then type `Esc-x` (or Meta-x, if you have "Use option as meta key" enabled in **Terminal > Preferences > Settings > [profile] > Keyboard**). This will ask for a command to execute. Enter `shell`.

To see a list of commands you can use in Shell Mode, enter `Control-h m`. Here are the ones for moving the cursor to the previous/next prompt:

```
C-c C-n         comint-next-prompt
C-c C-p         comint-previous-prompt
```

These commands would also be useful:

```
C-c C-r         comint-show-output
C-c C-o         comint-delete-output
```